# Ruby CSV: ignoring empty column

Tags: ruby, string, csv

Is it possible to ignore or to replace with empty String, when the column is empty?
My CSV looks like this:

```
"DE","Klasse","Deutsch", "x"
"EN","Class","Carpenter",
"DE","Klasse","Mathe",
,,,
```

So not all the columns are filled. There are several empty columns. It retunrs an error :

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

What I did is :

```
csv_contents = CSV.read("path_to_csv", options)
str=["local, type, name"]
csv_contents.each_with_index do |row, i|
if row[3]==nil
  str << row[0] + ", " + row[1] + ", " + row[2] 
end
end
```

end 
I have to modify the csv because all the rows that have "x" in the last column should be deleted.
Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: How did you collect the `csv_contents`, show that part also..

Comment: @ArupRakshit alright. I'll do it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method to check if the value is nil. If so, return "".

```
def get_row(row, i)
  row.nil? ? "" : row[i]
end
```

Then, use it in your code:

```
str << get_row(row, 0) + ", " + get_row(row, 1) + ", " + get_row(row, 2)
```

Comment: @catwoman If this answer helped you, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: Yes, of course I will. I couldn't do it before, had to wait 8 min @Abdo

Comment: @Abdo Check out my one too :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to ignore or to replace with empty String, when the column is empty?

When you have a line like `foo,,bar,`,that means those columns are **blank**. Yes you are right, but **blank** mean those are already **empty string** (`""`). No point here, to replace an **empty string** with an **empty string** :-). Anyway you can ignore them obviously, when you will save those data in the output file.

> because all the rows that have "x" in the last column should be deleted.

That is possible, no doubt.

Here is how, I would do this :

```
require 'csv'

input_file_path = File.expand_path('input.csv',File.dirname(__FILE__))
output_file_path = File.expand_path('output.csv',File.dirname(__FILE__)) 

option = { :skip_blanks => true, 
           :quote_char => "\'", 
           :converters => lambda do |field|
             field.to_s.tr('"','')
           end
         }

CSV.open(output_file_path,'w',:force_quotes => true) do |out_row|
  CSV.foreach(input_file_path, option) do |in_row|
    row_to_add = in_row.reject(&:empty?)
    unless row_to_add.empty?
      row_to_add.last[/^\s*x$/i] ? out_row.puts(row_to_add[0..-2]) : out_row.puts(row_to_add)
    end
  end
end
```

**output**

```
"DE","Klasse","Deutsch"
"EN","Class","Carpenter"
"DE","Klasse","Mathe"
```